# Change window name (output window) in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, user-interface, titlebar

Is there a way to change the window name in visual studio 2010. By window I mean the "output window" "Command window" "code definition window" names not title bar (already know you can do that)? I have purify and it shows no name in its window and its pretty annoying because if not selected it basically disappears because of that. I need a way to add a name to the blank purify window title bar. Any help?

[image]

Comment: thank you check out the image